# Jenkins Maven compilation error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

Hello I know this is a basic question but please help me to understand and resolve the issue, as I have no clue what is happening.

I have two projects lets say Project A and project B. Project A dependency is used Project B.

Scenario 1
When I build project A, it is build successfully and related jar file is available in my local repo and project B is build successfully with the dependent jar file.

Scenario 2
When I directly build Project B with the dependency of Project A in pom file I am getting compilation issues as the jar file is getting loaded from project repo.

Expected dependency (jar file) is available in the .m2 repository with the specified version and if I extract the jar file I am able to see the implementation classes but that is not getting recognized by my project while doing maven build.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a correct configuration, Maven would detect that it needs to build project B and project A in turn, and would use the version it just built to compile the second module. Are you using a parent POM? And are these two projects both modules of the same parent POM?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Project B has a dependency on project A, and they both have a common parent P. `mvn clean package` (local) worked fine with different versions for P in each project.

My Jenkins build failed on the maven-compiler-plugin, even though the plugin version as well as java-source and target versions were the same in both versions of the parent POM.

I fixed the build failure by updating both projects to the same version of the parent.

Comment: I thought this might be the scenario for us as well (difference in parent pom for child dependencies). However, after updated all to use the same we continued to see the same error. We upgraded from Maven 3.5.3 to 3.6.3 and we are no longer facing the issue--so my guess is that it's a combination of the items. I didn't see anything in Maven release notes for a fix of this nature, but since it's working for us now I'm going to leave well-enough alone. :)

Answer (score 0):

adding this in pom , worked for me

```
 <execution>
        <id>repackage</id>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).